# Submiting a form with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I am trying to submit this form when the Enter key in the textarea is pressed. It seems like it should work, but it doesn't. I get the alert, and It refreshes the page, but it doesn't submit the form. Whats wrong with it? thanks! Just to clarify, I want pressing the enter key to do the exact same thing as hitting the submit button.

```
<?php
//Doing stuff with the submitted form
?>

<form id='myform' action='' method='post'>
        <tr>
            <td><textarea id='but' class='messin' name='mess'    placeholder='Reply...'></textarea></td>
            <td><input class='messin' type='submit' name='submit'   value='Send'/></td>
        </tr>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#but").keyup(function(event) {

        if (event.which == 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert("Submit!");

        $("#myform").submit();
        location.reload();
        }
        }); 
        });
</script>
```

Comment: Why are you reloading after the submit?

Comment: you are repeating the id messin in both the input and the text area

Comment: I thought that was needed

Comment: Id must be unique. Class can be not unique. As @john said you haven't to reload page after submitting. What you want to achieve firstly? Applying from without page refresh? Or you just want to handle `enter` key in textarea?

Comment: When the enter key is pressed, I want it to send the form and refresh the page. The form is sent to this page.

Comment: Don't wrap a TR with a form tag.

Comment: Use an input instead of textarea then there's no need for javascript as the form is automatically submitted on enter.

Comment: That's not the problem, the submit button still submits it, but pressing enter doesn't

Comment: Can I make <input type='text'/> block bigger like a text area?

Comment: Sure use css set width and height.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that .submit() is not a blocking operation. This means that if you call something after which causes a navigation modification, you will abort your submission. Try not reloading the page.

BTW submission means always a (synchronous) redirection. If your intention is to submit an AJAX form (which will not automatically redirect), you should do the reload in the `complete` callback of the ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

You are using same id for both the form elements. Id's should be unique in nature. You can use class instead

```
 <td><textarea class='messin' name='mess'    placeholder='Reply...'></textarea></td>
 <td><input class='messin' type='submit' name='submit'   value='Send'/></td>
```

JS Change:

```
$(".messin").keyup(function(event) {

//code
});
```

Comment: I updated my code. But the form still doesn't submit

Comment: You have to call `$("#myform").submit();` without any preventDefault (btw you submitting preventDefault to keyup, not for submit) if `event.which == 13`. Also, you don't have to make reload after `.submit()`. Page will be reloaded on submit action. I wrote an answer for you. There are example of what I said in it. Check it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#but').keypress(function (event) {
  if (event.which == 13) {
    $('#myform').submit();
  }
});
```

Hope this code will help you.

**ADD** 
If you don't want to send form use `event.preventDefault();` or `return false;`. Look this example:

```
$('#but').keypress(function (event) {
  if (event.which == 13) {
    $('#myform').submit(
     // do some stuff with form
     event.PreventDefault(); // or return false; // return false == event.PreventDefault()
    );
  }
});
```